# Use the HttpURLConnection Response Cache

Tags: android, caching, httpurlconnection

We are advised [here](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/redundant_redundant.html#ResponseCache) to use the `HttpURLConnection` response cache by including and calling the `enableHttpResponseCache()` function:

```
private void enableHttpResponseCache() {
  try {
    long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    File httpCacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "http");
    Class.forName("android.net.http.HttpResponseCache")
         .getMethod("install", File.class, long.class)
         .invoke(null, httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
  } catch (Exception httpResponseCacheNotAvailable) {
    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP response cache is unavailable.");
  }
}
```

What I'm not so clear about is *where* we should be calling this function, when, and how often.  For example, if I'm making use of an `HttpURLConnection` in a Service started from an `AppWidgetProvider` every 30 minutes, should I call `enableHttpResponseCache()` from `onReceive()` of `AppWidgetProvider` before every `HttpURLConnection` is established, or only once, or what?